# script.googleusercontent.com refused to connect webapp href link not working

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, web-applications

The error I got in Google Chrome is following when clicked on the linked element.

> n-f22j6yycycwkqttwlgfk5eezyixnbwfyfih4bba-0lu-script.googleusercontent.com refused to connect.

Html element is this ->

```html
   <a href="" onclick="location.href = this.href+url+'?page=form2';return false;"> <img style="margin-right: 16px;" id="img1" height="200px" class="img-rounded" width="47%" src="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=16RE0CGxrEsXB9bBFj_Nq5jwTb5c8IMgU" alt="Image1"></a>
```

Note, "this.href" part has value empty. while url is variable stored the webApp Url.

Anyone has witnessed this problem and found how to fix it? It will save my day. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

### The problem arises from using `location.href` in Apps Script

Use instead `window.top.location`.

`<a href="" onclick="window.top.location = 'https://stackoverflow.com/';return false;"> <img style="margin-right: 16px;" id="img1" height="200px" class="img-rounded" width="47%" src="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=XXXXXXXXX" alt="Image1"></a>`

works for me.